# Moving a burger menu to the right side react-burger-menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a burger menu component using react-burger-menu component and it works fine, but I want it to move to the right side of the page and open it from the right side. I have tried right:0 and float:right in the CSS and tried to change the position system but either it doesn't move or the style gets ruined. How can I move the exact same menu to the right?

```
export default props => {
  return (
  // Pass on our props
    <Menu {...props}>
      <a className='menu-item' href='/'>
          Home
      </a>

      <a className='menu-item' href='/burgers'>
          Burgers
      </a>

      <a className='menu-item' href='/pizzas'>
          Pizzas
      </a>

      <a className='menu-item' href='/desserts'>
          Desserts
      </a>
    </Menu>
  )
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}

#page-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.bm-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}


.bm-item:hover {
  color: white;
}


.bm-burger-button {
  position: fixed;
  width: 36px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 36px;
  top: 36px;
  /* right: 0; */
  /* float: right; */
}


.bm-burger-bars {
  background: #373a47;
}


.bm-cross-button {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}


.bm-cross {
  background: #bdc3c7;
}


.bm-menu {
  background: #373a47;
  padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

.bm-morph-shape {
  fill: #373a47;
}


.bm-item-list {
  color: #b8b7ad;
}


.bm-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

and:

class HRPanel extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div id='App'>
        <SideBar pageWrapId='page-wrap' outerContainerId='App' />
        <div id='page-wrap'>

        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HRPanel
```

any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The menu opens from the left by default. To have it open from the right, use the right prop. It's just a boolean so you don't need to specify a value. Then set the position of the button using CSS.

```
<Menu right />
```

and

```
 .bm-burger-button {
    right: 0%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

fixing style like:

```
.bm-burger-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 36px;
  height: 30px;
  right: 36px;
  top: 36px;
  /* right: 0; */
  float: right;
}
```